# Notifying admin of query fails in JDBC/SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm designing a database with SQLite and JDBC using the following structure:

```
 public void update/add/delete() {

        try {

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

SQLException catches and prints the source of the error to the console if a query fails. I also want it to print to somewhere on the admin page in order to notify the admin that his/her query has failed. Is it possible?

Comment: Where do you want to print the info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
   }
```

toString() method was what I was looking for.